# change target answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a "whack-a-mole" style educational game for children where a question is given and they have to click on the right appearing number. For example when a sum like "2+2" is given the child must wait for a "4" to appear and click it. The question changes every time the correct answer is hit, but the problem is when the new question appears there is no right answer and every number you click adds to the wrong score. Can someone tell me why this keeps happening.

Here is the cases for the sums..

```
function correctlabels() {
    switch (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)) {
        case 1:
            check = sum1;
            $('#target').html('0 + 1 = ?');
            break;
        case 2:
            check = sum2;
            $('#target').html('1 + 1 = ?');
            break;
        case 3:
            check = sum3;
            $('#target').html('2 + 1 = ?');
            break;
        case 4:
            check = sum4;
            $('#target').html('2 + 2 = ?');
            break;
        case 5:
            check = sum5;
            $('#target').html('2 + 3 = ?');
            break;
        case 6:
            check = sum6;
            $('#target').html('3 + 3 = ?');
            break;
        case 7:
            check = sum7;
            $('#target').html('2 + 5 = ?');
            break;
        case 8:
            check = sum8;
            $('#target').html('2 + 6 = ?');
            break;
        case 9:
            check = sum9;
            $('#target').html('2 + 5 = ?');
            break;
    }
```

Here is a fiddle to show what I mean.. http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/8/

Comment: Thankyou, I am glad you like it @Mahan

Comment: Follow precisely your online tutorial.

Comment: why do you use this sumX functions? It's much easier(and faster) just to set the value of check like: `check=1;`

Comment: Could you give me an example? @Dirty-flow

Comment: you don't need all the sum functions, you can just set the value of check direct: `case 1:
           check = 1;
            $('#target').html('0 + 1 = ?');
            break;`
so just replace sum1 with 1, sum2 with 2 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you never re-add 'right' classes.
Try changing this:

```
    $('.character').each(function (index, character) {
        if (!check(parseInt(this.getAttribute("value")))) {
            $(this).addClass("wrong");
            $(this).removeClass("right");
        }
    });
```

to this:

```
    $('.character').each(function (index, character) {
        if (!check(parseInt(this.getAttribute("value")))) {
            $(this).addClass("wrong");
            $(this).removeClass("right");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("right");
            $(this).removeClass("wrong");
        }
    });
```

Nice game btw :)

Comment: Of course. Thankyou! I don't suppose you have any idea how I would add more than one sum per answer do you? @Inrbob

Comment: erm, you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/10/ could use some refinement but I don't think you'll end up with any instances of adding a negative number since the `Math.random()` is multiplied by `total`

Comment: @sMilbz just realised my last fiddle was complete so I've modified it further for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/pUwKb/13/ changed the whole `switch` statement as well...